# How to get Credit Card Memo data from Netsuite TransactionSearchAdvanced?

Tags: c#, netsuite

I'm newbie with the Netsuite's API.

I'm trying to get Credit Memo data (Invoice or Vendor Payment also) from TransactionSearchAdvanced.

Here is my code :

```
public void GetCreditList()
    {

        TransactionSearchAdvanced tsa = new TransactionSearchAdvanced();

        tsa.columns = new TransactionSearchRow();

        tsa.columns.basic = new TransactionSearchRowBasic();
        tsa.columns.basic.tranId = new SearchColumnStringField[] { new SearchColumnStringField() };

        tsa.criteria = new TransactionSearch();
        tsa.criteria.basic = new TransactionSearchBasic();

        tsa.criteria.basic.mainLine = new SearchBooleanField();
        tsa.criteria.basic.mainLine.searchValue = true;
        tsa.criteria.basic.mainLine.searchValueSpecified = true;

        tsa.criteria.basic.type = new SearchEnumMultiSelectField();
        tsa.criteria.basic.type.@operator = SearchEnumMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf;
        tsa.criteria.basic.type.operatorSpecified = true;
        tsa.criteria.basic.type.searchValue = new string[] { "_creditMemo" };

        this.login(true);
        SearchResult response = _service.search(tsa);

        // Process response
        if (response.status.isSuccess)
        {
            if (response.totalRecords > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= response.totalPages; i++)
                {
                    processCreditMemoSearchResponse(response);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _out.info("\nNothing found.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //_out.error(getStatusDetails(response.status));
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }


private void processCreditMemoSearchResponse(SearchResult response)
    {
        _out.info("\nThe search() operation for customers was run successfully.");
        _out.info("\n  Total Records = " + response.totalRecords);
        _out.info("  Total Pages = " + response.totalPages);
        _out.info("  Page Size = " + response.pageSize);
        _out.info("  Current Page Index = " + response.pageIndex);

        //Record[] records = response.recordList;

        SearchRow[] records = response.searchRowList;

        CreditMemo creditMemo;
        for (int i = 0, j = (response.pageIndex - 1) * _pageSize; i < records.Length; i++, j++)
        {
            creditMemo = (CreditMemo)records[i];
            _out.info(
                "\n  Record[" + j + "]: " +
                "\n    internalId=" + creditMemo.internalId);
        }
    }
```

And i get the error " Cannot convert SearchRow to CreditMemo"

I don't know what i have to do next.

Any hint is appreciate !!
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I found my own solution !

```
public void GetInvoiceList()
    {

        TransactionSearch transactionsSearch = new TransactionSearch();
        TransactionSearchBasic transactionSearchBasic = new TransactionSearchBasic();

        transactionSearchBasic.type = new SearchEnumMultiSelectField();
        transactionSearchBasic.type.@operator = SearchEnumMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf;
        transactionSearchBasic.type.operatorSpecified = true;
        transactionSearchBasic.type.searchValue = new string[] { "_invoice" };

        transactionsSearch.basic = transactionSearchBasic;

        this.login(true);

        SearchResult result = _service.search(transactionsSearch);
        List<Invoice> invoiceList = new List<Invoice>();

        if (result.status.isSuccess)
        {
            //RecordList recordList = result.recordList;
            Record[] records = result.recordList;

            if (records != null && records.Length != 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < records.Length; i++)
                {
                    Invoice invoice = (Invoice)records[i];
                    invoiceList.Add(invoice);
                }
            }
        }


        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```